# Typo3: bootstrap package and newsletter extension integration

Tags: typoscript, newsletter, typo3-extensions, typo3-7.6.x

In Typo3 I am using the the bootstrap package.

I need also an newsletter, which I created. But as an email, most of the styling is lost.

So my question is, has anyone already used the newsletter extension with the bootstrap package and can provide me with templates/TS? The TS should use `<table>` instead of `<div>`.

Typo3 7.6

Comment: What newsletter extension do you use?

Comment: newsletter
http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/newsletter

Answer (score 1):

That the most styling is lost, is IMHO obviuos. Newsletter styling is a very special thing. You must provide the newsletter templates that reflect your styling. The default is rather basic ...

The default template for the newletter is in EXT:newsletter/Resources/Private/Templates/Email/Show.html You must overwrite it with your own template.

Details, for how to write and test a good looking newsletter, you can refer to https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ or http://templates.mailchimp.com/?_ga=1.35791072.1385249247.1438156410

Comment: Unfortunately this with the template is only part of the truth. In the template the whole content` ìs taken, so the most of the work must be done in the TS before.
So the whole rendering need to be done in the pageTS of the newsletter page and would need completely different templates than what the boostrap theme provides.
At least this is my understanding so far.